# PlatformException(connect, Peripheral not found, null)

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I have an error connecting to a Bluetooth device in Flutter using flutter_blue package. The package version is **^0.6.3+1**.

This is my source code:

```
void scanForDevices() async {
    sController = StreamController();

    //await checkConnectedDevices();

    sController.addStream(FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults);

    FlutterBlue.instance.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 10));

    scanSubscription = sController.stream.listen((devices) async {
      final result = devices.where((currentDev) => currentDev.advertisementData.localName.contains((_dev as BaseDevice).psn)).toList();

      if (null == deviceToConnect && null != result && result.length > 0) {
        final dev = result.first;
        deviceToConnect = dev.device;
        print(dev.advertisementData.localName);

        try {
          await dev.device.connect();

          await checkState();

          setState(ViewState.Idle);
        } catch (e) {
          setState(ViewState.Idle);

          print(e);
        }

        //stopScanning();

        setState(ViewState.Idle);
      }
    });
  }

void stopScanning() async {
    print('stopping scan');

    await FlutterBlue.instance.stopScan();

    if (null != scanSubscription) await scanSubscription.cancel();

    if (null != sController) await sController.close();
  }
```

Works fine, but not always. For example:

- first time works fine
- second time doesn't work
- third time works fine
- fourth time doesn't work
- ...

Comment: Provide some details about the error, like complete exception  etc

Comment: Only returns a PlatformException(connect, Peripheral not found, null) exception. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with Flutter Blue package. Instead use flutter_blue_plus package for bluetooth operations.

PlatformException(connect, Peripheral not found, null) is an exceptions thrown by flutter package when ever it got an exceptions from the native operating system.

The exceptions often raise due to storage of previously connected device information and it wont be nil. To make it work you need to clear the instance of already existing flutter blue instance and initiate a new instance to perform bluetooth operations.

To Overcome the issue you can use the latest version of
**flutter_blue_plus: ^1.28.7.**

```
// Initially Start scanning
await FlutterBluePlus.startScan();

// Setup Listener for scan results after scanning
var subscription = FlutterBluePlus.scanResults.listen((results) {
        if (results.isNotEmpty) {
            // the most recently found device
            ScanResult r = results.last; 
            print('${r.device.remoteId}:"${r.advertisementData.advName}" 
            found!');
            // Stop scanning
            await FlutterBluePlus.stopScan();
            connectBleDevice(r.device);
          }
       },
       onError(e) => print(e);
    );


connectBleDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    // Connect to the device
    await device.connect();
}

disconnectBleDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {
     // Disconnect from device
    await device.disconnect();
}
```

Once after successful connect of Ble device you can perform disconnect and again try connect to it using the above mentioned steps. There will no issues in the new version of the **flutter_blue_plus: ^1.28.7** package as they are removing knownServices & lastValues on reconnection instead of disconnection.